# How to check if a swipe is within the bounds of a stack View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Stack Overflow,

I am trying to check if a swipe occurred within nested stack views. In my particular example, I have the following hierarchy:

- First Stackview

  - Second Stackview

    - Label
    - Label

I would like to get the coordinates of the second stack view and make sure that the user swipes within that box. How can this be done?

Thanks,
Marcocypher

Comment: Have you tried to add swipe to your second swipe view?

Comment: I guess you need to disable the interaction of First Stackview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is to attach a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to Second Stackview. It will only trigger when the user pans on that area.

The other option is to have the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` attached further up the stack and use the provided methods to test whether the location of the gesture was inside the view.

Here's an implementation of the action triggered by the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`:

```
@IBAction func gestureActivated(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    let location = sender.location(in: secondStackView)
    if secondStackView.point(inside: location, with: nil) {
        print("Hit Second Stackview")
    } else {
        print("Outside Second Stackview")
    }
}
```